# How can I exclude specific rows containing data from text to csv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, text

Here's what I'm using to parse a log file:

```
import csv
import os
import numpy


def remove_csv_columns(input_csv, output_csv, exclude_column_indices):
    with open(input_csv) as file_in, open(output_csv, 'w', newline='') as file_out:
        reader = csv.reader(file_in)
        writer = csv.writer(file_out)
        writer.writerows(
            [col for idx, col in enumerate(row)
             if idx not in exclude_column_indices]
            for row in reader)


with open("UserLog.txt", encoding="ISO-8859-1") as f, open('Delete.csv', 'w', newline='') as f2:
    writer = csv.writer(f2)
    writer.writerow(['Index', 'DATETIME', 'USER', 'ACTION', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'USER', 'ACTION'])

    i = 0
    for line in f:
        writer.writerow([i] + line.rstrip().split(';'))
        i += 1
        if i == 10000:
            break


remove_csv_columns('delete.csv', 'out.csv', (0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6))
os.remove("Delete.csv")
```

This is messy because it creates a .csv only to later delete it for a new one, but it does get at least half the job done. I'm only interested in log file data when the ACTION column starts with "Key Fob Entry: ". I want anything else, any other row, deleted in the final output. How can I do this? :/

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to show a few rows from an example input file and what your expected output would be? It would help to understand what you are trying to acheive

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
with open('out.csv', 'r') as inp:
    lines = inp.readlines()

with open('purged_csv_file.csv', 'w') as out:
    # We go line by line writing in the target file
    # if the original line does not include the
    # strings 'py-board' or 'coffee'
    for line in lines:
        if not 'UNSUCCESSFUL' in line and not 'Successful' and not 'INVALID' in line and not 'PASSWORD' in line:
            out.write(line)
```

Still messy because I'm just recreating many documents but it works :P

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining _how_ it works and _when_ to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).